# Post on facebook when I publish blog

Tags: facebook

I want to publish a facebook post the moment I publish a new blog on my website.Please help me to get this done.

Comment: You will have to use plugin for that. Search wp.org for such plugins.

Comment: Can you suggest me any

Comment: No. Asking to recommend a product (plugin, theme hosting provider), tool, library or off-site resource is out of scope of the site. [Search on Google](http://bfy.tw/lZ).

Answer (score 0):

As Robert hue said, you'll have to use a plugin for this. There are plenty in the [Plugin directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=publish%20facebook), but you could also write your own plugin (or add the code to your theme's `functions.php` file) if you can't find a suitable one or need more functionality.

You'll want to hook into the `publish_post` action.

For example:

```
function publish_post_to_facebook($ID, $post) 
{
    // Use the $post object to get information on the post, such as
    // the post_title

    // You could use the $ID of the post to generate a permalink,
    // i.e., get_permalink($ID)

    // Here would go your code to connect to Facebook and share the
    // the post. You would likely need to use a Facebook PHP SDK
}

add_action( 'publish_post', 'publish_post_to_facebook' );
```

Remember, in WordPress nearly everything is a type of post (including pages). You'd probably want to check that `$post->post_type == 'post'` (or your custom post type, if you're using one).

There's an example of the `publish_post` hook being used in the [Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post) in the Codex.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is for sync your blog post data with your facebook account right..?

You can actually sync your WordPress and Facebook accounts so that,
every time you post an article on your WordPress site, a link is
automatically shared on Facebook.

Please follow this URL : https://wordpress.org/plugins/social/

This could help you better.

Best of luck..!

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link I it displays nice blog on how you can post it on fb

http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-automatically-post-to-facebook-from-wordpress/